# Prevent old dll version loading

Tags: .net

I'm having a bit of trouble with a simple exe.  On the first machine I have .net 3.0, 2.0 (&1.1) and visual studio 2005.  When I build the application it correctly loads the 3.0 version of mscrt.dll.  I then built a deployment project containing the required libraries and installed it on a second machine which only has .net 2.0.  When I run the application it is apparent that it is using the wrong version.  If I check which dlls are loaded it shows both versions.

How do I prevent it from loading the old dll?  I don't have admin access to the machine so can't do anything about the config pc the machine.

Comment: Is your Project targeting .NET 3.0?  How are you checking the loaded assembly's version?

Comment: Document what mscrt.dll is and how it gets loaded.  It is not a standard DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [assembly version redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx).

> An application configuration file, machine configuration file, or a publisher policy file can redirect one version of an assembly to another.